# Performing stack operation to push string in java without collection api

Tags: java, stack

In my java program I want to perform stack operation like push and pop. I also want to push string in stack operation but when I try to push string. I get error mentioned in screenshot. How should I change push method in order to run the program successfully.

**code ::**

```
public class DataStack {

private static final int capacity = 3;  
 String arr[] = new String[capacity];  
 int top = -1;  

 public void push(String pushedElement) {  
  if (top < capacity - 1) {  
   top++;  
   arr[top] = pushedElement;    
   printElements();  
  } else {  
   System.out.println("Stack Overflow !");  
  }  
 }  

 public void pop() {  
  if (top >= 0) {  
   top--;  
   System.out.println("Pop operation done !");  
  } else {  
   System.out.println("Stack Underflow !");  
  }  
 }  

 public void printElements() {  
  if (top >= 0) {  
   System.out.print("Elements in stack : ");  
   for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {  
    System.out.println(arr[i]);  
   }  
  }  
 }  

 public static void main(String[] args) {  
  DataStack stackDemo = new DataStack();  

  stackDemo.push("china");  
  stackDemo.push("india"); 
  stackDemo.push("usa");    
 }
}
```

**Error::**

[image]

Comment: You can't store a string in an int array.

Comment: String stack[] = ...

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: why exactly you claim: `while pushing element it should print only one` your code actually prints whole stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `push()` method and underlying `arr` variable should be of `String` type.

```
String arr[] = new String[capacity];

public void push(String pushedElement) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is declared to store only integers .  Not to mention, the `stackDemo.push` method also declared to take in only int arguments.

```
int arr[] = new int[capacity];


public void push(int pushedElement) {
```

you should try pushing in integers.

```
  stackDemo.push(1);  
  stackDemo.push(2);  
  stackDemo.push(3);
```